# How to customize the jvm startup parameters in the gRPC-java startup script

Tags: grpc, java-opts

gRPC-version:
1.7.0

I want to add some JVM startup parameters to the gRPC-java startup script.
For example by customizing the CreateStartScripts Task or other methods.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use defaultJvmOpts variable:

```
task helloWorldServer(type: CreateStartScripts) {
    mainClassName = 'io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloWorldServer'
    applicationName = 'hello-world-server'
    outputDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'tmp')
    classpath = jar.outputs.files + project.configurations.runtime
    defaultJvmOpts = ["-XX:+UseG1GC"]
}
```

refer：
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/jvm/application/tasks/CreateStartScripts.html